# LINQ join in VB.NET return concrete type rather than anonymous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ query in VB.NET

```
Using db As New ReablementLSQLDataContext
                query = (From b In db.Visits
                             Join c In db.LinkStaffToVisits On b.ID Equals c.VisitID
                             Where c.StaffID = staffid And b.StartEpoch = newepochdatetime).ToList()

            End Using
```

When I run this, it returns a list of type anonymous which means its pretty useless if I want to access any of the data in it. How do I run this join statement and return a list of a concrete type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types as query results aren't so "useless", since you can always `foreach` over them (locally). Still, if you want a concrete type, you can add a select statement at the end and project the anonymous result into your type (supposed that you made this type and know which fields to use where), like (C# syntax)

```
var newQuery = query.Select(anon_x => new YourType(anon_x.field1, anon_x.field2, ...))
```

Comment: I found that I couldn't for each over them, or rather I could but there was no intellisense options for any of the values. I solved this by adding 'Select New ClassName()' to the end of the LINQ statement and was able to map the values into a concrete custom class. Adding .ToList() at the end gave me a list (I think) of this concrete class.

Comment: Well, having no intellisense doesn't mean anything. Since anonymous types are compiler generated, intellisense could have problems determining their properties' names. Although, I think sometimes it works, IIRC.

Comment: I get that it doesn't mean anything, but for me the ability to type 'Object.' then ctrl-space to see what the properties are makes life a lot easier than just getting the default list with GetType and ToString.

Comment: Did you compare the performance of the two queries? Does intellisense worth the performance hit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic version of `ToList` method. I am a `C#` developer and can provide syntax related to `C#` :

`.ToList<YourType>();`

For `VB.Net` version read : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx#Y0

Comment: Does `ToList` really convert? According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx, the type param is only for the source type. And I doubt that an anonymous type can be converted correctly to something else with a simple type conversion.

Comment: Dont you have a concrete type for `b` ? if yes, you can always add a `SELECT` clause to your LINQ as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737914). Then declare `query` as a `List` of same concrete type and it should work. Let me know if it dosent,then i will write a sample for you in `VB.Net`